# Не запускается сервер с помощью python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django

Начал изучать django, создал проект, попытался запустить сервер с помощью команды python manage.py runserver, но выдает ошибку. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\даня>cd C:\Django

C:\Django>cd myfirst

C:\Django\myfirst>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in w
rapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 395,
 in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382,
 in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72,
in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in c
heck_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _
load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in _
_get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in ur
l_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in _
_get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 581, in ur
lconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Django\myfirst\myfirst\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'articles'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.
py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 599, in
run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 584, in
start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 299, in
run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 305, in
run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 345, in
tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 361, in
snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 260, in
watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 105, in
iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 141, in
iter_modules_and_files
    resolved_path = path.resolve(strict=True).absolute()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\pathlib.py", line 1144, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\pathlib.py", line 196, in resolve
    return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 123] Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Файлы проекта:

**manage**

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myfirst.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**asgi**

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myfirst.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()
```

**settings**

```
import os,sys

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'apps'))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'gc*ar4(-%j00mj(9*imu)cq^3%klcpb4h-i71zn3r&l9(j$x2p'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myfirst.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myfirst.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**urls**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('articles/', include('articles.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

**wsgi**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myfirst.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**admin**

```
from django.contrib import admin
```

**apps**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ArticlesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'articles'
```

**models**

```
from django.db import models
```

**tests**

```
from django.test import TestCase
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name = 'index')
]
```

**views**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world!")
```

Comment: Проблема появилась после каких-то изменений или сразу не работало?

Comment: Не видит модуль `articles`. Файл `__init__` там есть?

Comment: @Александр, проблема появилась после изменений.Файл __init__ есть.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в файле **settings.py** есть настройка **INSTALLED_APPS** туда нужно добавить ваше app **articles**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'articles',
]
```

Comment: добавил, все равно ошибка. можно что-то еще попробовать?

Answer (score 0):

Понятное дело, для автора вопрос уже не актуален. Для тех, кто столкнется с чем то подобным, как я сегодня. Получил такие же отчеты об ошибках как в этой теме. Только начинаю разбираться с Django, причем не первый раз. В общем я решил проблему заменив строку в urls.py:

```
from . import views
```

на

```
from {appname} import views
```

У меня всё.